# jax-rs 2.0 requirements in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, jax-rs

First of all, I would like to say I'm new to web services.

I'm trying to use jersey 2.2 in eclipse kepler 4.3 which requires jax-rs 2.0 . However when I'm trying to create a new dynamic web project and choose jax-rs 2.0 as a facet, it gives me an error that dynamic web module 3.1 or higher is required .. the latest version I see of dynamic web module when creating the project is 3.0 and I can't find the place to install a newer version?

Answer (score 1):

You only have that option when the server runtime being targeted supports 3.1. There's also a bug about that requirement: http://bugs.eclipse.org/416704 .